# Добрый день. не понимаю почему возникает ошибка

Tags: python

```
 aliens = []
for alien_number in range(0,30):
    new_alien = {'color': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}
    aliens.append(new_alien)
for alien in aliens[0:3]:
    if alien ['color'] == 'green':
        alien ['color'] = 'yellow'
        alien ['speed'] = 'medium'
        alien ['points'] = 10
            elif alien ['color'] == 'yellow':
                alien ['color'] = 'red'
                alien ['speed'] = 'fast'
                alien ['points'] = 15
for alien in aliens[:5]:
    print(alien)
print('...')
```

Comment: сама ошибка выглядит так   
    elif alien ['color'] == 'yellow':
IndentationError: unexpected indent     При этом. сам код скопирован из книги, пробовал менять отступы ни это не помогло, помогите пожалуйста разобраться

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный* код для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Код выложите не картинкой, а текстом!

Comment: я подумал, что по коду и так понятно, по этому не стал расписывать, учту и в следующий раз постараюсь оформить корректно

Comment: @user426995 сейчас пожалуйста выложите код текстом. Я сейчас потратил не мало времени, чтобы переписать с картинки и в итоге у меня не выдает ни одной ошибки. Хотя мог просто скопировать.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков готово,

Comment: @user426995  `elif alien ['color'] == 'yellow':` никогда не будет срабатывать так как на вход у вас всегда идут зеленые и срабатывает только первый if. + Ошибки в отступах

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как и ожидалось. Проблема в отступах. Видимо, вы не так пробовали.

Попробуйте скопировать вот этот код:

```
aliens = []
for alien_number in range(0,30):
    new_alien = {'color': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}
    aliens.append(new_alien)
#Не знаю зачем я это делаю, но
#устанавливаем первому пришельцу желтый цвет до цикла
aliens[0]['color'] = 'yellow'
for alien in aliens[0:3]:
    if alien ['color'] == 'green':
        alien ['color'] = 'yellow'
        alien ['speed'] = 'medium'
        alien ['points'] = 10
    elif alien ['color'] == 'yellow':
        alien ['color'] = 'red'
        alien ['speed'] = 'fast'
        alien ['points'] = 15
for alien in aliens[:5]:
    print(alien)
print('...')
```

Результат программы:

```
{'color': 'red', 'points': 15, 'speed': 'fast'}
{'color': 'yellow', 'points': 10, 'speed': 'medium'}
{'color': 'yellow', 'points': 10, 'speed': 'medium'}
{'color': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}
{'color': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}
...
```

Как мы видим первый пришелец стал красным.

Comment: В книге написано "Цикл можно расширить, добавив блок elif для превращения желтых пришельцев
в красных" Если скопировать данный код, то пришельцы так и остаются желтые и зелёные

Comment: @user426995 1) Вообще вопрос был не в этом, а в том что у вас ошибка возникала 2) Изначально у вас все зеленые, вы у первых трех меняете зеленый, на желтый, а в блок `elif` вы не попадете т.к. у вас изначально все зеленые. А потом вы выводите 5-ых. 3-х желтых и 2-х зеленых. Хотя бы одного из 3-х первых сделайте желтым (перед циклом) и увидите красного.

Comment: @user426995 хоть это и не в тему вопроса, но я дополнил код изменением цвета у первого пришельца на желтый, чтобы после цикла появился красный. Так же прошу если вам помог один из двух приведенных ответов, отметить его как "Правильный ответ" нажав на галочку слева от ответа :)

Comment: получается проблема в примере? код который я описывал, взят целиком из книги "Изучаем Python. Программирование игр, визуализация данных, веб-приложения | Мэтиз Эрик" стр 115

Comment: @user426995 не знаю, может дальше об этом сказано где-то. Может вы пропустили.

Answer (score 0):

кажется вы не там резмистили elif он должен быть на одном уровне с if,  а вы сдвинули его правее.

Comment: Это первое, что пробовал делать, но это не помогает, если их сдвинуть на один уровень, то elif полностью игнорируется